# How to reduce UISlider frame height?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, uislider

It turns out that `UISlider` has a lower limit for its frame height. On `iOS 6` it's 23px and on `iOS 7`it's 34 px. But that's too much for me and i need to make it smaller. How can i do that without using `CGAffineTransformMakeScale` (i tried that already and don't like how it looks)? Or maybe i'm just missing something really simple?

Comment: Use autolayout Pin height to UISlider take IBOutlet of height and then set constant to 23; I m not sure whether it is correct way.

Comment: i don't use IB so could you please drop few lines of code for example?

Comment: Considering you are doing it by using xib/storyboard. Select UISlider Go to -> Editor -> Pin -> "Height". 
Now take IBOutlet
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *sliderHeight; Set in .m self.sliderHeight.constant = 23;

Comment: Just customize your `UISlider` by setting minimum and maximum track images, and set wanted images height.

Answer (score 1):

There's no properties you could use to do that.
I did find a [github project](https://github.com/SebastienThiebaud/STTimeSlider/tree/master/STTimeSlider) which allows you set the the height of the bar.

Or have a look at the [results](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=slider) on Cocoa Controls for 'Slider'.

Answer (score 0):

Assign height constraint to slider in storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use images of smaller size :

```
   [slider setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Thumb"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];   // slider thumb should be square image
        [slider setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Thumb"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted]; // slider thumb on touch
        [slider setMinimumTrackImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"rMin"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];     // thumb left part
        [slider setMaximumTrackImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Max"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];   // thumb right part
```

choose images carefully, now its photoshop work